# Cross-browser compatibility problem with IOS

Tags: css, cross-browser

**My problem arises with animations box-shadow in CSS3.**

[Google(windows/android)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXDHv.png)

[Safari/Google(IOS/MAC)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAV3J.png)

**For animations i writen prefix moz, webkit, o, default, but this don't work.
What is the problem?**

```
.home__number {
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
color: #fff;
font-size: 64px;
border-radius: 30% 70% 70% 30%/30% 30% 70% 70%;
-webkit-animation: home__item1 10s infinite;
-moz-animation: home__item1 10s infinite;
-o-animation: home__item1 10s infinite;
animation: home__item1 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes home__item1 {
0% {
  border-radius: 30% 70% 70% 30%/30% 30% 70% 70%;
  box-shadow: 0 -150px 70px -120px #6730ec inset,
   0 -220px 70px -120px #7984ee inset, 0 -280px 70px -120px #a9d2ff inset;
}
25% {
  border-radius: 58% 42% 75% 25%/76% 46% 54% 24%;
}
50% {
  border-radius: 50% 50% 33% 67%/55% 27% 73% 45%;
  box-shadow: 0 -140px 70px -120px #a9d2ff inset,
   0 -210px 70px -120px #7984ee inset, 0 -280px 70px -120px #6730ec inset;
}
75% {
 border-radius: 33% 67% 58% 42%/63% 68% 32% 37%;
}
100% {
 box-shadow: 0 -150px 70px -120px #6730ec inset,
  0 -220px 70px -120px #7984ee inset, 0 -280px 70px -120px #a9d2ff inset;
}
```

}

**For other keyframes writen same.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a full answer because I don't have a workaround, but here's a mini exploration of the problem in case it helps your investigations.

Stripping everything out of the CSS except for the box-shadow we can still see a problem in IOS Safari which is not there on say Edge in Windows 10. Here's the simplest code, using red, green, blue for contrast:

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  box-shadow: 
    0 -150px 70px -120px red inset,0 -220px 70px -120px green inset,0 -280px 70px -120px blue inset;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Which on Edge gives the expected result:
[image]

and on IOS Safari gives:
[image]

In fact, if we use only one box shadow you can just see that there is still a vertical bar on the left hand side.

Nothing I have tried, such as minimising the blur, has got rid of the bar so far but it may be worth experimenting with, say, putting another 'dummy' color at the front to see if that can be minimised in some way. (It is the first color that is taken as the one 'on top' in a box shadow).

Edit: I have since found this https://medium.com/@andrea.verlicchi/inset-box-shadow-rendering-bug-on-safari-ios-13-4-6bf4256a1ee0 which reports a black vertical bar and relates it to large negative blur radius on inset box-shadow in IOS13, but I have not been able to see how you could use their workaround.